# Item without column name defined, would it be saved to the database field?

Tags: oracleforms

Oracle Forms Builder 10g, there is a data block which is referencing to a table,  property of database item of one item is set to Yes, but column name is empty to this item.

Would the field in database being updated to the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if item name is the same as database column name.